# A weird contains (*) jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

Hello I have this html structure.

```
<span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px 0px; "></span>
```

I just want to check the state when the style changes to

```
<span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px -50px; "></span>
```

so I guess this code will match:

```
var isChecked = $('.yleis span.radio[style*="-50"]')?true:false;

console.log(isChecked);
```

But why is this always return true?

Comment: This is the attribute-contains selector [jQuery Documentation - Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a jQuery selector (`$('div)` etc) will always be a jQuery object. To turn this into a boolean of whether any results exist, check the length property. Anything other than 0 is true.

```
var isChecked = $('.yleis span.radio[style*="-50"]').length ? true : false;
```

You also don't need the : after radio.

http://jsfiddle.net/sfkkh/

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery call always returns a jQuery object, even if the selector matches zero elements.

Check the length of the jQuery object to see if it matched anything:

```
var isChecked = $('.yleis span.radio[style*="-50"]').length > 0;
```

(As Plutor noted, the colon shouldn't be in the selector.)

Answer (score 2):

You assume that an empty jQuery object (no elements matched) would yield you `false` and a non-empty one `true`. This is not true - a jQuery object is always "something". You want to check whether *it's empty*. Use `$(...).length > 0` instead (which gives you a boolean - no ternary operator needed).